# C# XNA Cannot autodetect which importer to use for "AceBackground.xnb"

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

xna game studio, gives following error

Cannot autodetect which importer to use for "AceBackground.xnb".

There are no importers which handle this file type. Specify the importer that handles this file type in your project.

Regards,

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you did to get that error? I'm guessing that you tried to put a `.xnb` file into a Content Pipeline Project in Visual Studio?